# How to pass data from realm results to an array list?

Tags: java, android, realm

I have executed a realm transaction and have passed a json array for my data model.

```
public void execute(Realm realm){
    for (int i = 0; i<menuListArray.length(); i++ ){
        try{
            JSONObject jObject = menuListArray.getJSONObject(i);
            user.setMenuTitle(jObject.getString("title"));
            realm.copyToRealm(user);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), ProfileLandingActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

I have executed the following query to fetch the object

```
public RealmResults<User> getUserMenu() {
    return realm.where(User.class).distinct("menuTitle");
}
```

I am using the realm result `getUserMenu()` in another activity:

```
RealmResults<User> users = RealmController.initialize(this).getUserMenu();
```

Now if I execute `users.first()` I can only fetch the first data from JSON and if I execute `users.last()` I can only fetch the last data from JSON. But I have to fetch all the data from realm result users. How shall I fetch all the data from JSON? I have to pass those data into an array list.

Pardon me if any of my statement in question haven't met the developer language as I am trying to become one.

Comment: Try to pass menu title string array list via intent.

Comment: I can do that, but with later purpose for data, I might have to use realm right?

Comment: Please check copyToRealm Overloaded methods : https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/Realm.html#copyToRealm-io.realm.RealmObject-, I think it allow you to copy multiple object iterable list.

Comment: What is `RealmController`?

Comment: A separate class file to handle all the realm queries with respect to function requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use Intent outside of for loop as below...

```
public void execute(Realm realm){
        for (int i = 0; i<menuListArray.length(); i++ ){
            try{
                JSONObject jObject = menuListArray.getJSONObject(i);
                user.setMenuTitle(jObject.getString("title"));
                realm.copyToRealm(user);
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), ProfileLandingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

and you can get all title using this code

```
for (User userData : users ) {
            String title = userData.getMenuTitle();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you @sagar pithiya

Comment: As I am new to development, would you kindly suggest to pass all the "title" data into an array.

Comment: If you read all titles into an array, you'll lose auto-update and lazy evaluation. -_- use a RecyclerView and a RealmRecyclerViewAdapter

Answer (score 0):

```
public void execute(Realm realm){
    for (int i = 0; i < menuListArray.length(); i++) {
        try{
            JSONObject jObject = menuListArray.getJSONObject(i);
            user.setMenuTitle(jObject.getString("title"));
            realm.insert(user);
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), ProfileLandingActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Then in other activity, show the elements using a RecyclerView with [RealmRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters).

```
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<User, UserViewHolder>(getContext(), RealmController.initialize(this).getUserMenu(), true) {
        @Override
        public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new UserViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_user_item, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
            User user = getData().get(position);
            holder.menuTitle.setText(user.getMenuTitle());
        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```